# Is it possible to create an icon on the home screen of a phone using reactJS?

Tags: reactjs, mobile

I built a website with reactjs and the client wants that the web automatically creates a link on the phone home screen that opens chrome to the specific url of my website.
Is this possible without wrapping the reactjs with another framework like Cordoba, Ionic or React Native?

Thank you so much

Comment: I believe progressive web apps (PWA) allow you to add an icon to the phone that just links straight to the app. And I think it's not too hard to add that functionality (though I've never done it myself, so might be wrong). You can have a look into them, might be what you need: https://web.dev/install-criteria/

Comment: You could also include some instructions for users to add it to their home screens. However, automatically adding an icon to someone's home screen would be a horrible feature that is bound to upset users. Good thing this isn't possible :)

Answer (score 1):

A web application has no access to the device's internal APIs. Web applications are naturally subject to the browser's features, restrictions and limitations in which it is running on. Even native applications has to request access from the user to have such permissions. What your client asks is, regretably, impossible.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the above answer by @Lux Ilustre. You can't add the application link to the phones homepage without the users permission. But it is possible to make your website installable with a `PWA`. You can create a `PWA` with a manifest file and a service-worker file which makes possible to install the website to the users phone and load assets from cache which makes it possible to make some parts of your website function offline.